# glossaries-extra discardperiod and abbreviation long form

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

When using the `discardperiod` functionality from `glossaries-extra` the following period gets unduly discarded when an explicitly long form is used:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  abbreviations,
  shortcuts=abbr,
]{glossaries-extra}

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{discardperiod}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{retainfirstuseperiod}{true}

\newabbreviation{dr}{Dr.}{Doctor}

\begin{document}

% This is OK.
\ab{dr}. \ab{dr}.

% This is still OK.
\as{dr}.

% This period gets unduly discarded.
\al{dr}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyone happens to know a way to get this case correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could come up with something reasonable, even if this one was trickier than I hoped for.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  abbreviations,
  shortcuts=abbr,
]{glossaries-extra}

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{discardperiod}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{retainfirstuseperiod}{true}

\newtoggle{glsenddot}
\NewDocumentCommand{\glsdot}{}{\global\toggletrue{glsenddot}.\@}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrifperiod}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{glsenddot}
    {%
      \global\togglefalse{glsenddot}%
      \new@ifnextchar.{\@firstoftwo{#1}}%
    }
    {\@secondoftwo{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
\preto\glsxtrpostlink{\global\togglefalse{glsenddot}}

\newabbreviation{dr}{Dr\glsdot}{Doctor}
\newabbreviation{abc}{ABC}{Aaaa Bbbb Cccc}

\begin{document}

% This is OK.
\ab{dr}.  \ab{abc}. \ab{abc}. \ab{dr}.

% This is still OK.
\as{dr}.

% This period is now in place.
\al{dr}.

\ab{abc}.

\end{document}
```

[image]